# DrRacket Locals and Lambdas

Tags: racket

I'm currently doing an assignment for a class where we have to utilize lambdas and locals to redefine functions we've previously defined. I don't really want to just have it written out for me since the issue is something I'm going to face sooner or later.

I don't understand how a local works, and as for a lambda I'm not sure what some of the clauses mean.

Here's an example of a lambda function I made that involved taking only the even numbers from a list and squaring them:

```
(define (even-squares lon)
    (foldr (lambda (x y) 
              (if (even? x) (cons (sqr x) y)
                  y)) '() lon))
```

This worked fine for the problem, but I don't fully get lambda in this situation. I understand that it makes x and y, which are two elements from the list the main focus, and performs an operation regarding them. In this case, an if statement is made where x is tested to be even and then added to a list if it is, or removed otherwise. The function then continues with the y from the first case as the new x and the next element of the list as the new y. Please let me know if this is incorrect in any sense.

What I don't understand in the slightest is why the "else" clause of the if statement is just a y, what does that do?

On the other hand, I am at a complete loss for what a local does. From my little understanding that the old videos my college provides to us gave me, it's a function that produces a function, but I don't understand what it's meant to take in after the definitions clause.

If anyone could provide examples or just explain the concepts I'd greatly appreciate it. Thank you :)

Comment: `lambda` makes new functions; in this case one used as the first argument to `foldr` that takes two arguments - see [its documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29) for details about what that function does and what is passed as its arguments. Hint: It's not two elements of the list. `x` and `y` are perhaps not the best names here.

Comment: That's not an "if statement", it's a conditional expression (there are no statements at all, only expressions). The value of `(if c t e)` is `e` if `c` is `#f`, and `t` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

I took the following code from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72679425/using-racket-isl-to-define-functions-using-list-abstractions-and-local-lambda)- the answer has a little bit better argument names:

```
(define (even-squares-only lon)
  (foldr (lambda (element result)
           (if (even? element)
               (cons (sqr element) result)
               result))
         '()
         lon))
```

As you can see, the first argument `element` is an element of the list and the last argument `result` is an intermediate result/ accumulator.

At the beginning, `result` is an empty list. In each step, one element from the list is tested. If it meets the condition, it's added to the `result` squared. If it doesn't, you continue with an unchanged `result`.

See also documentation for [`foldl`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) and [`foldr`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldr%29%29).

As for the `local`: if you are familiar with `let` or `letrec`, `local` is similar, just with a little bit different syntax. if [documentation entry](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp-langs/intermediate-lam.html#%28form._%28%28lib._lang%2Fhtdp-intermediate-lambda..rkt%29._local%29%29) didn't help you, here is an example:

When rewriting your function, you can decide to remove `lambda` from `foldr` and put it somewhere else. So, without any knowledge of `local`, you can do this:

```
(define (reducing-fn element result)
  (if (even? element)
      (cons (sqr element) result)
      result))

(define (even-squares-only lon)
  (foldr reducing-fn
         '()
         lon))
```

`reducing-fn` is defined globally, so any other function than `even-squares-only` can use it too.

But you can also define it locally, so it can be used only in the body of `local`. No other function can use the definition from `local` and it can also increase readability because you see that `reducing-fn` "belongs" only to `even-squares-only`. So, you would rewrite it like this:

```
(define (even-squares-only lon)
  (local [(define (reducing-fn element result)
            (if (even? element)
                (cons (sqr element) result)
                result))]
    (foldr reducing-fn
           '()
           lon)))
```